# How to replace multiple different characters using preg_replace() function?

Tags: php, preg-replace

How to replace `@` and `.` symbols from an email address with `-` symbol using `preg_replace()` function in php ?

Comment: You might be looking for `strtr` rather.

Comment: what's the point in such a replace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your search patterns are just strings, using string replacement using `str_replace` is better as suggested in other answer.

Here goes the `preg_replace` based answer:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[@.]/','-',$str);
```

Answer (score 24):

There is no need to use `preg_replace`.

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead:

```
$output = str_replace(array('@', '.'), '-', $input);
```

Comment: Its working...thanks..But there isn,t it can be done using preg_replace() function?

Comment: Sure thing you can use `preg_replace`. Read @codeaddict's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my ase I had to replace the character '-' and delete it from a text value:

> $var= preg_replace('/-/','',$var);

That worked for me, just in case someone want to substitute just one character. That way i give the user the possibility to enter the text they want, but the data will be corrected when it get to the server.