# Is there any better way doing this with preg_replace only?

Tags: php, preg-replace

What I am looking for by using preg_replace is replacing ". or ' or space" from string with "-".

Like replacing `"Some St. Street O' Corner"` into `"some-st-street-o-corner"`.

How i am achieving this is by using below way.

```
$string = "Some St. Street O' Corner";

$new_string = preg_replace('/\\.|\\'/', '', $string);

$final_string = str_replace(' ', '-', $new_string);
```

Is there any better way to get it done by just using preg_replace?

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/lMdJT

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks for quick solution. It's working great. But if . or ' at the end, it's adding -. which is quite obvious but can that be stopped from adding in case string ends with . or ' https://3v4l.org/j2P5t
I am just not good in regex thing :(

Comment: https://3v4l.org/SvelS

Comment: Great. https://3v4l.org/SvelS it works the way I wanted. Thanks for taking your time to solve my concerned @Wiktor. Cheers!!

Comment: This question already has answers here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995106/how-to-replace-two-different-characters-with-one-character-using-preg-replace

anyway, this link is not solution of what i asked for.

Comment: @AmitSharma: Only use `preg_replace` is false good idea to slug a string. If you want something appropriate to do that in one shot, use the intl transliterator. See the new [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string).